# How can I find text within an wchar_t* array

Tags: c++

Sorry for what maybe will be an easy question to answer, but here we go.

```
itemname2 = tsection.htmlText.Data;
int rf = itemname2.rfind("'>");
itemname2 = itemname2.replace(0, rf + 2, "");                                               
WriteLogFile(itemname2);
```

The code above works perfectly if I was to be passing a string into itemname2, however 
tsection.htmlText.Data = wchar_t *TArray::Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn `itemname2` into a `std::wstring` and then do it very similar way:

```
int rf = itemname2.rfind(L"'>");
itemname2 = itemname2.replace(0, rf + (2*sizeof(wchar_t)), "");
```

You need to use `L` prefix to let compiler interpret lietral string as a wide one.

Comment: See I know I was missing something completely simple... thank you for the answer, works perfectly.